# Unable to debug Android c++ app on device (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: android-ndk, visual-studio-2015

Using the Android tools for C++ in VS15, I've been unable to get the debugger working... VS is able to install the app on the test device without an issue, but debugging does not work.

```
Unable to start debugging. Non-debuggable application installed on the target device. Required file '/data/data/com.AndroidTest/lib/gdbserver' could not be found on the device. Please reinstall the debuggable version.
```

I've inspected the apk; it does have gdbserver.

The device I'm using is a LG G 7.0 (V400) running Android 5.0.2. The project targets API level 19, but I've also tried targeting API level 21 and still the same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the exact same problem, "Unable to start debugging" with the LG V400. The solution to that was to root the tablet, and it works just fine now.

I used this in order to root my device:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/avicohh/files/Android/LG_One_Click_Root_by_avicohh.exe/download

After that I've found some Samsung phones also suffer from that same issue.

Comment: Hmph, was hoping I wouldn't have to root it. Thanks for the link though. I might give that a try.

Comment: Yep, the one click root did the trick. It was really as simple as running that tool. Debugging through VS magically worked after applying the root.